# How to solve -Error- Column 'RefName' in field list is ambiguous?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I want to create table based on the `RefName` with `e05c%` character. But why the message shows `RefName` in field list is ambiguous?

Below is my code:

```
 DROP TABLE  IF EXISTS TotalZSummary;
 CREATE TABLE TotalZSummary

 SELECT RefName,
        COUNT(CellName) AS CellCount,
        SUM(CellCount*Z_perInst) AS SumZ,
 FROM find_interface c LEFT JOIN
      stdCellVariant v 
     ON c.RefName = v.RefName
 WHERE RefName LIKE 'e05c%'
 GROUP BY RefName;
```

**this is my new code:**

```
DROP TABLE  IF EXISTS TotalZSummary;
CREATE TABLE TotalZSummary

SELECT
c.RefName,
COUNT(c.CellName) AS CellCount,
SUM(c.CellCount*v.Z_perInst) AS SumZ,
FROM `find_interface` c
LEFT JOIN `stdCellVariant` v ON c.RefName=v.RefName
WHERE c.RefName LIKE 'e05c%'
GROUP BY c.RefName
;
```

the error shown is Error- You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `find_interface` c LEFT JOIN `stdCellVariant` v ON c.RefName=v.RefName WHER' at line 1.

Comment: this is the new code i used:

Comment: You shouldn't have a comma at the end of "SUM(c.CellCount*v.Z_perInst) AS SumZ,". A comma there means you are going to add another select column, but you don't.

Comment: the error disapper. but there are another error. if i use SUM(CellCount*v.Z_perInst) AS SumZ, there error is -Error- Unknown column 'CellCount' in 'field list'
but if i use SUM(c.CellCount*v.Z_perInst) AS SumZ, the error is -Error- Unknown column 'c.CellCount' in 'field list'. what should i do? which command i need to use?

Comment: You can't use the name of a column in the same selection list. You need to use the value of the column instead, so COUNT(c.CellName) instead of CellCount

Comment: do i need to change the previous command to "SUM(COUNT(c.CellName) * v.Z_perInst)" ? i dont really understand. sorry.

Comment: i tried to use "SUM(COUNT(c.CellName) * v.Z_perInst)"  but still fail. the error is -Error- Invalid use of group function

Comment: This is now really a different question - I would start a new question with a title something like 'Invalid use of group function error in mysql', show your new code, and see what response you get. I'm not a expert in grouping issues in mysql, but somebody who is is more likely to see a new question about it than to look into this one, which has a title about a different problem.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you have more than one table in a query, **qualify** the column references!

```
SELECT c.RefName, COUNT(c.CellName) AS CellCount, 
       SUM(v.CellCountZ_perInst) AS SumZ, 
       SUM(v.CellCountUV1_TxTotZ) AS SvtZ, 
       SUM(v.CellCountNOM_TxTotZ) AS NomZ,
       SUM(v.CellCountUV2_TxTotZ) AS HvtZ
FROM find_interface c LEFT JOIN
     stdCellVariant v
     ON c.RefName = v.RefName
WHERE c.RefName LIKE 'e05c%'
GROUP BY c.RefName ;
```

I am guessing that all the other columns come from `stdCellVariant`.

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer my question. i get the data for RefName and CellName  from table 1. then the Z_perInst, UV1_TxTotz, NOM_TxTotZ and UV2_TxTotZ from table 2. i want to join all the data based on the RefName where 'e05c%'. thats means both table have RefName. i still cant solve it using your code.

Comment: @sitinadhirahZainurin . . . Well, you should use the appropriate alias for the reference.  Normally in a `LEFT JOIN`, a `COUNT()` is used on the *second* table not the *first*.  If on the second table, then the value will be `0` when there is no matching row.

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer my question. i get the data for RefName and CellName  from table 1. then the Z_perInst, UV1_TxTotz, NOM_TxTotZ and UV2_TxTotZ from table 2. i want to join all the data based on the RefName where 'e05c%'. thats means both table have RefName. i still cant solve it using your code.

Comment: @sitinadhirahZainurin . . . What is the issue with this code?  Your `on` condition specifies that `refname` is the same in both tables, if it exists in the second.  This query should be doing exactly what you want.

Comment: hi, i attached the new code at my question but it still produce error. kindly help me:)

Comment: @sitinadhirahZainurin . . . You have a comma before the `FROM` clause.  BTW, it is rude to change a question that has been answered.  New questions should be asked as *new* questions, not as edits to existing questions and not as comments.

Comment: sorry but i dont know how to paste the code that u gave me at the comment. that why i try to paste it at the question ;(

Comment: i tried to remove  comma but still have error. there are another error. if i use SUM(CellCountv.Z_perInst) AS SumZ, there error is -Error- Unknown column 'CellCount' in 'field list' but if i use SUM(c.CellCountv.Z_perInst) AS SumZ, the error is -Error- Unknown column 'c.CellCount' in 'field list'. what should i do? which command i need to use?

Answer (score 3):

This part:

```
WHERE RefName LIKE 'e05c%'
GROUP BY RefName
```

You reference `RefName` column, but `RefName` is a column in table `find_interface` AND in table `stdCellVariant`. Even if you are already saying that they must match, all references to columns that might be repeated need to be prefixed with table name or alias:

```
WHERE C.RefName LIKE 'e05c%'
GROUP BY C.RefName
```

Also in this example, as you are using `LEFT JOIN`, using `C` or `V` as alias will have totally different effect. Try it out!

---

From your edition:

```
SUM(c.CellCount*v.Z_perInst) AS SumZ, -- here!
FROM `find_interface` c
```

Remove the comma just before the `FROM`, since you are not listing any other column to select.

Comment: Hi, i already try with this code. but still have error. the error is -Error- You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `find_interface` c LEFT JOIN `stdCellVariant` v ON c.RefName=v.RefName WHER' at line 1

Comment: @sitinadhirahZainurin I've added where the problem is.